# Magento 2.4.5-p1 cache issue

Tags: magento2, cache

I'm using EaDesgin custom module to print the PDF invoice since I used Magento 2.4.2. After we did upgrade to Magento 2.4.5-p1, we faced an issue when we try to edit the pdf template from the template list page. When I open ite from google chrome on computer has static IP address it shows only the last template id but when I use google chrome browser from different computer has dynamic IP it shows all templates IDs. I attached screen shots from both computers. Please help to fix this issue.[Screen shot with correct view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrq8e.png) - [Screen shot with incorrect view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIflY.png)

[image: Screen shot with correct view]
[image: Screen shot with incorrect view]

Comment: please check the below answer and update me if it's working for you or not. If it's not working then please share your code here.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try to replace the data source section**

```xml
<dataSource name="your_grid_list_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">your_grid_list_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">item_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">item_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">item_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
```

**Note: Please add your data source name and primary key column name.**